# Why do we need primitive assembly after vextex post processing?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, parallel-processing, opengl-es

The output of Vertex post processing is in Window space, here after (based on standard pipeline ) primitive assembling comes, why?

I know primitive assembly happens in many stages like before clipping, but why do we need PA at this stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primitive assembly happens before clipping, but the specification isn't clear on *exactly where* before it. In fact:

> After a primitive is formed, it is clipped to a clip volume.

That's *all* it says about its location (outside of needing to do it for tessellation or GS's).